# Расстояние от точки до прямой С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, вычислительная-геометрия

у меня есть следующий код по нахождению расстояния между точкой и прямой:

```
template<typename T>
using point_t = std::pair<T, T>;

template<typename T>
using line_segment_t = std::pair<point_t<T>, point_t<T>>;

template<typename CoordinateType>
double get_distance_between_point_and_line_segment(const 
line_segment_t<CoordinateType>& line_segment, const point_t<CoordinateType>& point) noexcept
{ 
    const CoordinateType x = std::get<X_COORDINATE>(point);
    const CoordinateType y = std::get<Y_COORDINATE>(point);

    const CoordinateType x1 = std::get<X_COORDINATE>(line_segment.first);
    const CoordinateType y1 = std::get<Y_COORDINATE>(line_segment.first);

    const CoordinateType x2 = std::get<X_COORDINATE>(line_segment.second);
    const CoordinateType y2 = std::get<Y_COORDINATE>(line_segment.second);

    const double double_area = abs((y2-y1)*x - (x2-x1)*y + x2*y1 - y2*x1);
    const double line_segment_length = sqrt((x2*x2 - x1*x1) + (y2*y2 - y1*y1));
    return double_area / line_segment_length;
}
```

Казалось бы все хорошо, но если я например по даю на вход линию `{ (5;1), (1;5) }`, то при вычислении ее длины я получаю 0, и следовательно дальше деление на ноль... В моей ситуации я не могу проверить на результат `line_segment_length` и выбросить скажем исключение если длина равна нулю. Мне нужно узнать хотя бы примерную длину между точкой и отрезком, когда `line_segment_length` стала равна нулю. Как это все можно реализовать?

Comment: Возьмите листочек в клеточку, нарисуйте на нем координатную сетку, отметьте точки с координатами (5;1), (1;5), проведите между ними линию и убедитесь, длина этой линии будет не ноль...

Comment: Потому что в формуле должен быть квадрат разности, а у вас разность квадратов: `sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правильно сказал @AlexKrass, у вас ошибка в строке

```
const double line_segment_length = sqrt((x2*x2 - x1*x1) + (y2*y2 - y1*y1));
```

Длина (Евклидова норма) - это корень из суммы квадратов разностей координат. Должно быть

```
const double line_segment_length = sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
```

или, после раскрытия скобок

```
const double line_segment_length = sqrt(x2*x2 - 2*x2*x1 + x1*x1 + y2*y2 - 2*y2*y1 + y1*y1);
```

Comment: Если нет задачи написать непонятный код, то скобки раскрывать не надо.